# Migrating existing related fields to another model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```py
class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    office = models.ManyToManyField(Office)


class Basic(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="basic_profile"
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)


class Administrator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, models.CASCADE, related_name="admin_profile")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

At the moment, each user is either attached to an `Administrator` or `Basic` instance. Each user can be part of many `Office`.

I want to have it so that the user can manage multiple `Basic` objects while those `Basic` objects can be part of separate offices. To do this, I believe I would need to migrate the `office = models.ManyToManyField(Office)` over to the `Basic` and `Administrator` objects.

Keep in mind that the `Basic` model will be seen by Administrators within the `Office` model. That's why I want to have some separation.